# Map to same dataframe column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe like below

```
Token,Time,Path,Duration,Response
1, 142830,NaN , IOC, NEW
1,142832,0,NaN,NEW_CONFIRM
1,142836,1234,NaN,TRADED
2, 142830,NaN , IOC, NEW
2,142832,0,NaN,NEW_CONFIRM
2,142836,1234,NaN,NOT_TRADED
3, 142830,NaN , GTC, NEW
3,142832,0,NaN,NEW_CONFIRM
3,142836,1234,NaN,NOT_TRADED
```

My intent is to take all Tokens where Duration is IOC

```
orders = df.loc[df.Duration == 'IOC', 'Token'].unique()
```

Take Path value from  token where Response is CONFIRM (This is tricky)
Return something like below

```
Token,Time,Path,Duration,Response
1, 142830,0,IOC,TRADED
2, 142830,0,IOC,NOT_TRADED
```

Every token will will always have a confirm (if not then ignore that token). Every token would either be traded or not traded. In the end I would group how many tokens from Path 0 got traded and not traded, similarly for path 1, path 2, etc (but path has to be taken only where Response type is confirm) Any other Path value can be wrong (1234 is a garbage value)

Adding a new example

```
>>> df
     OrderID            TimeStamp  ErrorCode Duration          ResponseType  \
0    3000000  1488948188555841641        NaN      IOC                   NaN   
1    3000000  1488948188556444675          0      NaN     NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM   
2    3000000  1488948188556448153          2      NaN         TRADE_CONFIRM   
3    3000001  1488948658787676012        NaN      IOC                   NaN   
4    3000001  1488948658787811582          1      NaN     NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM   
5    3000001  1488948658787824862          2      NaN         TRADE_CONFIRM   
6    3000002  1488949064945887091        NaN      IOC                   NaN   
7    3000003  1488949109654115659        NaN      IOC                   NaN   
8    3000003  1488949109654294973          1      NaN     NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM   
9    3000003  1488949109654299930      16388      NaN  CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM
```

Function made using @jezrael solution

```
>>> def f(x):
...     #print (x)
...     #check if NEW_CONFIRM and IOC in group
...     if  ((x.ResponseType == 'NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM').any() and (x.Duration == 'IOC').any()):
...         #filter data - output scalar
...         a = x.loc[x.Duration == 'IOC', ['TimeStamp','Duration']]
...         print(a)
...         a1 = str(a['TimeStamp'].item())
...         a2 = a['Duration'].item()
...         b = x.loc[x.Response == 'NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM', 'ErrorCode'].item()
...         c = x.loc[x.Response.str.isin(['TRADE_CONFIRM', 'CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM']), 'ResponseType'].item()
...         #return series with index for align data
...         return pd.Series([a1, a2, b, c], index=df.columns[1:])
... 
>>> df2 = df.groupby('ErrorCode').apply(f).dropna(how='all').reset_index()
>>> df2
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [index]
Index: []
```

Expected op

```
OrderID, TimeStamp,ErrorCode,Duration,ResponseType
3000000,1488948188555841641,0,IOC,TRADE_CONFIRM
3000001,1488948658787676012,1,IOC,TRADE_CONFIRM
3000003,1488949109654115659,1,IOC,CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
def f(x):
    #print (x)
    #check if NEW_CONFIRM and IOC in group
    if  ((x.Response == 'NEW_CONFIRM').any() and (x.Duration == 'IOC').any()):
        #filter data - output scalar
        a = x.loc[x.Duration == 'IOC', ['Time','Duration']]
        a1 = str(a['Time'].item())
        a2 = a['Duration'].item()
        b = x.loc[x.Response == 'NEW_CONFIRM', 'Path'].item()
        c = x.loc[x.Response.str.contains('TRADED'), 'Response'].item()
        #return series with index for align data
        return pd.Series([a1, a2, b, c], index=df.columns[1:])

#apply function anr remove NaN rows
df = df.groupby('Token').apply(f).dropna(how='all').reset_index()
print (df)
   Token    Time Path Duration    Response
0      1  142830  IOC        0      TRADED
1      2  142830  IOC        0  NOT_TRADED
```

EDIT:

Only some typos in column names was there:

```
def f(x):
    #print (x)
    #check if NEW_CONFIRM and IOC in group
    if  ((x.ResponseType == 'NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM').any() and (x.Duration == 'IOC').any()):
        #filter data - output scalar
        a = x.loc[x.Duration == 'IOC', ['TimeStamp','Duration']]
        a1 = str(a['TimeStamp'].item())
        a2 = a['Duration'].item()
        b = x.loc[x.ResponseType == 'NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM', 'ErrorCode'].item()
        c = x.loc[x.ResponseType.isin(['TRADE_CONFIRM', 'CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM']), 'ResponseType'].item()
        #return series with index for align data
        return pd.Series([a1, a2, b, c], index=df.columns[1:])

#apply function anr remove NaN rows
df = df.groupby('OrderID').apply(f).dropna(how='all').reset_index()
print (df)
   OrderID            TimeStamp ErrorCode  Duration          ResponseType
0  3000000  1488948188555841641       IOC       0.0         TRADE_CONFIRM
1  3000001  1488948658787676012       IOC       1.0         TRADE_CONFIRM
2  3000003  1488949109654115659       IOC       1.0  CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM
```

EDIT:

For testing lengths of data use:

```
def f(x):
    #print (x)
    #check if NEW_CONFIRM and IOC in group
    if  ((x.ResponseType == 'NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM').any() and (x.Duration == 'IOC').any()):
        #filter data - output scalar
        a = x.loc[x.Duration == 'IOC', ['TimeStamp','Duration']]
        a1 = str(a['TimeStamp'].item())
        a2 = a['Duration'].item()
        b = x.loc[x.ResponseType == 'NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM', 'ErrorCode'].item()
        c = x.loc[x.ResponseType.isin(['TRADE_CONFIRM', 'CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM']), 'ResponseType'].item()
        #return series with index for align data
        if len(a) > 1:
            print (a['TimeStamp'])
        if len(x.loc[x.ResponseType == 'NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM', 'ErrorCode']) > 1:
            print (x.loc[x.ResponseType == 'NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM', 'ErrorCode'])
        if len(x.loc[x.ResponseType.isin(['TRADE_CONFIRM', 'CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM']), 'ResponseType']) > 1:
            print (x.loc[x.ResponseType.isin(['TRADE_CONFIRM', 'CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM']), 'ResponseType'])
        return pd.Series([a1, a2, b, c], index=df.columns[1:])

#apply function anr remove NaN rows
df = df.groupby('OrderID').apply(f).dropna(how='all').reset_index()
print (df)
```

Comment: If instead of traded not_traded, we had yes and no, would we need to take 1 more variable?

Comment: I am writing email to you, give me a sec.

Comment: But it seems you need change`x.Response.str.contains('TRADED')` to `x.Response.isin(['yes', 'no'])`, but now am only on phone

Comment: I found a problem in the output. Path and Duration column names have changed, also ( group has to be created by path, in sample data there is only 1 path=0 )

Comment: So is possible create new sample data with desired output?

Comment: Added my exact terminal output and dataframe

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar `

Comment: It means there are multiple `IOC` values per group, or multiple `NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM`.

Comment: multiple `IOC` is possible test by `df = df[df.groupby('OrderID')['Duration'].transform(lambda x: (x == 'IOC').sum()) > 1 ]` and multiple `NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM` by `df = df[df.groupby('OrderID')['ResponseType'].transform(lambda x: (x == 'NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM').sum()) > 1 ]
`

Comment: both return `Empty DataFrame
Columns: [OrderID, TimeStamp, ErrorCode, Duration, ResponseType]
Index: []
`

Comment: `  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1347, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 709, in f
    return func(g, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in f
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 326, in item
    return self.values.item()
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar`

Comment: I think we should create 3 dataframes and then map IOC orderIDs to NEW_CONFIRM erroCodes, then use that merged result to map it to TRADE_CONFIRM or Cancel_confirm. ( if this approach is easier)

Comment: same error :(   `File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 709, in f
    return func(g, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in f
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 326, in item
    return self.values.item()
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar`